# Robocopy 1326 Error

Tags: robocopy

How to fix Robocopy Error 1326? Unknown username and bad password?

I'm trying to back up the files in the workstations without a domain, to put into a file server that is a member of a domain.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you think you need to do considering what the error message says?

Comment: I guess its the permission. I'd already allow file sharing and turn off the firewall. I'm sorry I am new to robocopy.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to work around your problem would be to make an IPC$
connection, before running robocopy. So:

NET USE \server\IPC$ /u:username password